# Request IP logs from Twitter

Tags: twitter, privacy

According to the [privacy section](https://twitter.com/privacy) at Twitter, it seems that the IPs used for access are logged

> Log Data may include information
>   such as your IP address, browser type, the referring domain, pages
>   visited, your mobile carrier, device and application IDs, and search
>   terms.

I know on Facebook to review this information, just means going to the security settings. Is there any similar method to request IP logs on Twitter?

Answer (score 1):

Highly unlikely. If you contact Twitter through a support ticket ([here](https://support.twitter.com/forms)), then they might possibly give it to you, but it's a potential data protection act thing and they probably won't want to give it to you.